# xquery plugin for eclipse that allows me to run xquery code against xml documents

Tags: eclipse, xquery

Is there any xquery plugin for eclipse, with which I can create and run xquery code against XML files? The only one I saw till now is Oxygen XML but that is a paid one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install **[XQDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/XQDT)** ( XQuery Development Tools).

The update site for XQDT is listed [here](http://www.xqdt.org/html/index).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, there's Oxygen XML.  There's also some XQuery support in WTP.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Eclipse Plugin for Xquery (XQDT). Reference at https://wiki.eclipse.org/XQDT/Installation